# Given eigenvector, find value of P

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that the following matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 2 \\ P & 2 & 1 \\ 14 & -4 & 10 \end{pmatrix}

has eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, how do I find the value of $P$?

I do not know what to do here, please help.

Comment: What do to is to write down what it means for $(1,2,3)$ to be an eigenvector, and then follow your nose --- there's really not much choice in what to do next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: By definition, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then we have $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$. 
Multiply $\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ to your matrix $A$ and set it equal to $\lambda \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$, you can find $\lambda$ and $P$.